# Tomcat standalone accessing from external ip

Tags: tomcat, ip, external

I have tomcat server running fine from eclipse, but when i use standalone tomcat i cant access it from external ip only from localhost.. does anybody know why this happens??

Answer (score 3):

Find `server.xml` file under `/conf` directory in your Tomcat installation dir. Find the `<Connector>` declaration and add `address="0.0.0.0"`:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="0.0.0.0"
```